# SWITCH CASE for MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, switch-statement

i want to ask about select case in ms access. from what i get is for db2
can anyone help to change the sql for ms access 2000

```
SELECT DISTINCT 

    CASE WHEN STORECODE='JPAT' THEN

        CASE WHEN PARTNO LIKE 'A%' THEN 

            ITEMNAME||'(NIV-'||SECTIONNO||')'

            WHEN PARTNO LIKE 'STSB%' THEN 

        ITEMNAME||' (NIV-'||SECTIONNO||')'

    ELSE

        ITEMNAME||'('||PARTNO||'-'||SECTIONNO||')'

    END

ELSE

ITEMNAME||'('||PARTNO||'-'||SECTIONNO||')'

END

    AS INPUTTEXT,

        IDX||':'||PARTNO||':'||BATCHNO||':'||ITEMTYPECODE||':'||TOOLTYPECODE||':'||ITEMCATEGORYCODE||':'||MATERIALTYPECODE||':'||SECTIONNO AS INPUTVAL

from ITEM  where idx > 0   and (storecode)='JPAT'
```

thanks

Comment: You can maybe show some sort of effort? You actually ask to translate a whole query and not only a case statement. As a start, in MS Access `CASE` = `Switch()` and `||` = `&`

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access, this would look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       IIF(PARTNO LIKE 'A*', ITEMNAME & "(NIV-" & SECTIONNO & ")"
           IIF(PARTNO LIKE "STSB*", ITEMNAME & " (NIV-" & SECTIONNO & ")"
               ITEMNAME & "(" & PARTNO & "-" & SECTIONNO & ")"
              )
          ) AS INPUTTEXT,
    (IDX & ":" & PARTNO & ":" & BATCHNO & ":" & ITEMTYPECODE & ":" &
     TOOLTYPECODE & ":"& ITEMCATEGORYCODE & ":" & MATERIALTYPECODE &
      ":" & SECTIONNO
    ) AS INPUTVAL
FROM ITEM 
WHERE idx > 0 AND storecode = "JPAT";
```

Notes:

- The comparison `storecode = 'JPAT'` is not needed in the `SELECT` because it is in the `WHERE`.
- The string delimiter in MS Access is `"`, not `'`.
- The string concatenation operator in MS Access is `&`.
- The wildcard in `LIKE` in MS Access is `*`.
- MS Access doesn't support `CASE`.  I find `IIF()` to be sufficient for this case (pun intended).